# Show Opportunity Line Items in rendered PDF Visualforce page on a Force.com profile

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, force.com, pdf, opportunity-lineitem

We have a requirement on our custom object bid to show the opportunity line items in a table on a visualforce page when selected by a user on a Force.com licence. We have the functionality working whereby an extender class gets and sets the ID via an opportunity lookup which works when the user can read the opportunity but doesn't show to our Force.com users. We've seen this working in principal on another platform but we can't seem to recreate the logic, we've found with most things a text formula lookup or a workflow field update is an easy work around but can't seem to figure out the easy fix for this.

I'll attach the extender class and visualforce page below hoping that someone can offer some guidance on a workable fix.

```
public class bidproducts
{
public List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems { get; set; }

Public bidproducts( ApexPages.StandardController std )
{
    if( std.getRecord().Id != null )
    {
        Go_Or_No_Go__c con = [ Select Id, Opportunity__c from Go_Or_No_Go__c    where Id =: std.getRecord().Id ];

        lineItems = [ Select Id, Opportunityid, Opportunity.Name ,   PricebookEntry.Name, TotalPrice, Quantity, Product2.Name, Description, Ad_Hoc__c, Gross_Margin_Percentage__c, Gross_Margin_Currency__c from OpportunityLineItem where Opportunityid =: con.Opportunity__c ];
    }
    else
    {
        lineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    }
}         
}



<apex:page standardController="Go_or_No_Go__c" extensions="bidproducts"      renderAs="pdf" showheader="false" sidebar="false">          
     <apex:form >
       <head>
       <style> 
        body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
        .companyName { font: bold 30px; color: red; }  
    </style>
</head>
    <center>
    <h1>OCS Go/No Go Script</h1>
    <h2>{!Go_or_No_Go__c.Bid__r.Owner.Name} - {!Go_Or_No_Go__c.Bid__r.Opportunity_Name__c}</h2>
    </center>
<body>
<h2> Account Information </h2>

<apex:pageblock >
<b>Description</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.bid__r.Account_Description__c}
<br/>
<br/>
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!Go_or_No_Go__c.Bid__r}" width="75%" var="ac" border="0.5" >
<apex:column value="{!ac.Credit_Score__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!ac.Credit_Rating__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!ac.Credit_Comment__c}" />
</apex:pageblockTable>
<br/>
<b>Existing Business</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Existing_Business__c}<br/>
<br/>
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!Go_or_No_Go__c}" width="100%" var="r1" border="0.2" >
<apex:column value="{!r1.Decision_Maker_Name__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!r1.Decision_Maker_Job_Title__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!r1.Decision_Maker_Map_to_OCS__c}" />
</apex:pageblockTable>
<br/>
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!Go_or_No_Go__c}" width="100%" var="r2" border="0.2" >
<apex:column value="{!r2.Other_Name_1__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!r2.Other_Job_Title_1__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!r2.Other_Map_to_OCS_1__c}" />
</apex:pageblockTable>
<br/>
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!Go_or_No_Go__c}" width="100%" var="r3" border="0.2" >
<apex:column value="{!r3.Other_Name_2__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!r3.Other_Job_Title_2__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!r3.Other_Map_to_OCS2__c}" />
</apex:pageblockTable>
<br/>
<h2> Opportunity Information </h2>
<b>Description</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.bid__r.Opportunity_Description__c}      <br/>
<b>Locations</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Locations__c}<br/>
<br/>
<b>Bid Submission Date</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Bid__r.Bid_Submission_Date__c}    <br/>
<b>Service Start Date</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Bid__r.Service_Start_Date__c}  <br/>
<br/>
<b>Key Reasons to Bid</b><br/>
&bull; {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reason_1__c}<br/>
&bull; {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reason_2__c}<br/>
&bull; {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reason_3__c}<br/>
<br/>
<b>Site References and Reasons</b><br/>
&bull; {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reference_1__c} -        {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reason_for_Reference_1__c} <br/>
&bull; {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reference_2__c} - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reason_for_Reference_2__c} <br/>
&bull; {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reference_3__c} - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Reason_for_Reference_3__c} <br/>
<br/>
<b>Terms and Conditions</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Terms_and_Conditions__c}
<br/>
<b>Known Competition</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Known_Competition__c}
<br/>
<h2>Product Summary and Estimated Value</h2>
<b>Estimated Annual Value</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Bid__r.Annual_Value__c} <br/>
<b>Term of Contract</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Bid__r.Term__c} <br/>
<b>Estimated Contract Value</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Bid__r.Contract_Value__c} <br/>
<b>Estimated Capex</b> - {!Go_or_No_Go__c.Estimated_CAPEX__c} <br/>
<br/>

<apex:pageblockTable value="{!LineItems}" width="100%" var="ml" border="0.5">
<apex:column value="{!ml.Product2.Name}" />
<apex:column value="{!ml.Description}" />
<apex:column value="{!ml.Ad_Hoc__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!ml.TotalPrice}" />
<apex:column value="{!ml.Gross_Margin_Percentage__c}" />
<apex:column value="{!ml.Gross_Margin_Currency__c}" />
</apex:pageblockTable> 
</apex:pageblock>
</body>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks,

Kev

Comment: what's an `extender` class ? did you mean a controller `extension`?

Comment: I did sorry, the extension is shown above the VF page. I think the problem may simply be that the force.com licence holder can't see the opportunity line items and therefore to make these visible to that profile we would need to clone this information onto a custom object and then pull that into the VF page.